# How to upload file into folder present in GCS bucket android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage

i am following this github tutorial to upload files into GCS bucket

https://github.com/thorrism/GoogleCloudExample

images are uploading into bucket successfully.

but i want to upload file into folder present inside bucket

for example

KS_bucket is bucket name and images is a folder name present inside KS_bucket.

i tried to specify bucket name like this

KS_bucket/images or KS_bucket/images/

but i am getting invalid bucket name error

```
. W/System.err: {
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com. W/System.err:   "code" : 400,
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com. W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/ W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com. W/System.err:     "message" : "Invalid bucket name: 'kS_bucket/images'",
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com. W/System.err:     "reason" : "invalid"
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com. W/System.err:   } ],
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com. W/System.err:   "message" : "Invalid bucket name: 'ks_bucket/images'"
2020-09-27 13:04:01.416 32172-32247/com..W/System.err: }
```

**the method iam using to upload is**

```
 public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, String filePath)
            throws Exception {
       
        Storage storage = getStorage();

        StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
        object.setBucket(bucketName);

        File file = new File(filePath);

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            String contentType = URLConnection
                    .guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
            InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType,
                    stream);

            Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(
                    bucketName, null, content);
            insert.setName(file.getName());
            insert.execute();
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
```

expecting some help on this , thanks.

Comment: Hey there, just to make sure, have you already created the GCS bucket on your project? If so, does it have that name ("ks_bucket")?

Comment: yes i can upload files to bucket , but i want to upload files to folder inside bucket

Answer (score 0):

you are trying here to set a bucket name with "/" in it which is not valid in Cloud Storage. what you need to do is to change the name of the file including its folder name when before you insert it in the bucket. `setName` is what you need to use here:

```
insert.setName('folder/filename');
```

something like that

Comment: Thanks @methkal khalawi